# How can we use Lyft Webhooks for driver trip status?

Tags: webhooks, lyft-api

Can I able to fetch trip status and data using webhook in driver account? I have tried but I am not getting any response in webhook URL, we tried using live lyft account and still no any response.

Please help, if anyone has a solution to this problem.
Looking forward to a response.

Thanks, in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are 2 ways to obtain the trip status.

Make sure you have the Webhook URL set in your app settings:

[image: Webhook Url textfield in Lyft App Settings]

When the webhook posts the json will look similar to:

```
    {
  "event_id": "ed595871-6b2f-5b22-99ae-a848ee763701",
  "href": "https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides/123456789",
  "occurred_at": "2017-07-26T11:03:50+00:00",
  "event_type": "ride.status.updated",
  "event": {
    "origin": {
      "lat": 37.76734,
      "lng": -122.40626,
      "eta_seconds": 60,
      "address": null
    },
    "passenger": {
      "rating": "5",
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "image_url": "https://lyft-app-img.s3.amazonaws.com/production/profilePicture/12345",
      "user_id": "123456789"
    },
    "requested_at": "2017-07-26T18:03:38+00:00",
    "route_url": "https://www.lyft.com/sr/abcdefg",
    "ride_id": "123456789",
    "destination": {
      "lat": 37.77653,
      "lng": -122.39215,
      "eta_seconds": null,
      "address": null
    },
    "driver": {
      "phone_number": "+15555555555",
      "rating": "4.9",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "image_url": "https://lyftapi.s3.amazonaws.com/production/photos/320x200/123456_driver.jpg"
    },
    "can_cancel": [
      "driver",
      "passenger",
      "dispatcher"
    ],
    "status": "accepted",
    "location": {
      "lat": 37.765975,
      "bearing": 270,
      "lng": -122.406034
    },
    "generated_at": "2017-07-26T18:03:50+00:00",
    "vehicle": {
      "color": "Red",
      "make": "Chevy",
      "license_plate": "ABCDEFG",
      "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/lyftapi/production/photos/stockcarphotos/whitebg/640x400/2015/chevy/bolt/red/12345.png",
      "year": 2015,
      "license_plate_state": "CA",
      "model": "Bolt"
    },
    "ride_type": "lyft",
    "pricing_details_url": "https://www.lyft.com/pricing/SFO",
    "ride_profile": "personal"
  }
}
```

You can pick the webhook.status from there.

The 2nd way is to long poll the ride via the GET /ride/:id endpoint.  This will also return you the ride.status.

Online reference:
https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference#ride-request-details

Potential ride states:
https://developer.lyft.com/docs/ride-states